# Past perfect vs past simple-- had been asleep/ was asleep

Tags: past-perfect

It was 5 in the morning, I **had been** asleep for 5 hours.

It was 5 in the morning, I was asleep for 5 hours.

What's the difference in their meaning?

Comment: I had been asleep for five hours. (length of time provided) / or: I had been sleeping for five hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Five in the morning is an instant in time: you can't be asleep for five hours within that instant, so the second sentence is not correct. If you were asleep for five hours at some point before **now**, you can use *past simple*:

> I was asleep for five hours

You can be asleep for five hours **before** five am, and you use *past perfect* to express this:

> It was 5 in the morning, I had been asleep for 5 hours.